# How to select only one type of value for shared id?

Tags: mysql

I wasn't sure how to word this but this is what I am looking for:

[image]

Currently my table looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `RANK()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY common_id ORDER BY id) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, string, common_id
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```